# Any way to pass an element from one context to another?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a meteor template that looks something like the following. Essentially I would like to pass something from my parent template to my child. Is there a way to do this?

```
<template name="parent">
Hello my name is {{name}}
{{#each children}}
    {{> child}}
{{/each}}
</template>

<template name="child">
Hello my name is {{child_name}} and my parent's name is [not sure what to do]
</template>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the dotdot operator to traverse to parent views.

```
<template name="parent">
Hello my name is {{name}}
{{#each children}}
    {{> child}}
{{/each}}
</template>

<template name="child">
Hello my name is {{child_name}} and my parent's name is {{../name}}
</template>
```

[See demo here](http://meteorpad.com/pad/CofDb3WLA8QYCDoo4) and [documentation here](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata)